# Papa Parse: How to catch error if remote CSV is inaccessible?

Tags: javascript, papaparse

When using [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/), you can access CSV errors via `result.errors` within the `complete` callback, but how do I catch error if remote CSV is inaccessible (e.g. 404)?

```
Papa.parse(csv_remote_url, {
  download: true,
  header: true,
  complete: function(result) {
    console.log(result.errors);
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the **error** prop same as **complete**.

```
Papa.parse(csv_remote_url, {
  download: true,
  header: true,
  complete: function(result) {
    console.log(result.errors);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});
```